# Prevent fixed position element from moving towards the left when resizing window?

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is the logo element not to move towards the left when I resize the window, despite the fixed position. Is there a way?

```
#logo {
        top:20px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-177.6px;
        width:355.2px;
        height:148.8px;
        position:fixed;
    }
```

Comment: don't use relative values for positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `left: 50%` to a fixed value, such as `left: 200px;`

Comment: Wow!!! This is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you very much! But I've noticed that there's a problem coming out with it, which is that when i zoomout the (logo) element will zoomout towards the left... Text-align:center doesn't solve.. Know anything?

Comment: @GiorgioVitanza Please post a new question for that, so more people will be able to see it, and provide a demo with it i.e. jsfiddle.net